# Claim Public Service Health and Dental Care Plan premiums?

Tags: income-tax, canada

I've never had enough medical expenses to actually claim them before, but this year, I did.  Working through my software, I was referred to [line 330](https://www.canada.ca/en/revenue-agency/services/forms-publications/tax-packages-years/general-income-tax-benefit-package/5000-g/general-income-tax-benefit-guide-federal-tax-credits-schedule-1.html#Line330):

> **Eligible medical expenses**...premiums paid to private health services plans (other than those paid by an employer, such as the amount shown in box J of your Quebec Relevé 1 slip)

I'm not in Quebec, and my employer is the Gov. of Canada (Treasury Board, technically).  The health and dental plans are public in the sense that it is for Public Service employees, but not to the general public.  The employer sort of plays for it, but by docking one's salary.  There doesn't appear to be a box indicating the total premiums in the T4 slip.

**Are these premiums claimable?**  I've never done that before.

Comment: do you have a box with an 85 as the code written in  in the other section?

Comment: Yes, there is a box 85 with some menial amount.  For box 85, the explanatory text on the back says "Employee-paid premiums for private health services plans – See line 330 in your tax guide."  I'm using StudioTax, which automatically populates data fields using data from CRA.  I will check whether this was done for box 85.  Thanks.